# How to modify WooCommerce Bookings products-templates.json to include date range in availability?

Tags: json, templates, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I wish to modify the products-templates.json file that stores the many types of booking templates.  How do I include a date range availability (see the screenshot)?

[image: shown here]

In the JSON below, is how time-based availability looks like divided into different time slots - `time1`, `time2`,...

```
{
  "slug": "tourist-activity",
  "name": "Tourist Activity",
  "short_description": "Booking daily tours for an activity? This is your starting point. You can book tours with vary cost and types of guest.",
  "scenario": "OPTION A: You're offering a tour with a maximum capacity of 25 people. Tours are daily and each last two hours. The tour prices differ for adults and children so you have set up two pricing groups.<br><br>OPTION B: You provide tours that can accommodate up to 25 people. They are daily two-hour tours. You put together two pricing categories due to the tour costs for adults and kids being different.",
  "features_utilized": [
    "Maximum capacity per tour (persons)",
    "Varying ticket price based on age (cost)",
    "Multiple events on certain days (resource availability)"
  ],
  "products_used": [
    "WooCommerce",
    "WooCommerce Bookings"
  ],
  "product_thumbnail": "product-1.png",
  "front_end_display": "product-1-FE.png",
  "back_end_display": "product-1-BE-1.png",
  "is_virtual": true,
  "duration": 2,
  "duration_unit": "hour",
  "duration_type": "fixed",
  "qty": 25,
  "default_date_availability": "non-available",
  "availability": {
    "time1": {
      "type": "time",
      "bookable": "yes",
      "priority": 10,
      "from": "10:00",
      "to": "12:00"
    },
    "time2": {
      "type": "time",
      "bookable": "yes",
      "priority": 10,
      "from": "14:00",
      "to": "16:00"
    },
    "time3": {
      "type": "time",
      "bookable": "yes",
      "priority": 10,
      "from": "18:00",
      "to": "20:00"
    }
  },
  "has_persons": true,
  "has_person_types": true,
  "has_person_qty_multiplier": false,
  "has_person_cost_multiplier": true,
  "min_persons": 1,
  "max_persons": 25
}
```